# I can't use Spectrum Analyzer after a Transf Fun

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, simulink

I'm finding problems to use Spectrum Analyzer after a Transf Fcn block in simulink. I need to measure the response frequency after and before the blok Transfer Fcn because I need to know with my filter is working in the right way. So any alternatives for this ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I find a way by using [Low-Pass Filter (Discrete or Continuous)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/ref/lowpassfilterdiscreteorcontinuous.html).